# running multiple process in current shell (using {} ) with atleast one command to be run as background

Tags: bash

I want to run a sequence of commands as the current process with one command running in background like below (does not work)

```
 { echo "long running process" & ; sleep 3; } # error sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

However when there is a single background process it works, as below

```
 { echo "long running process" & } # works
```

Why does running multiple commands with one command running in background is not allowed in bash?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `&` is a valid [command delimiter](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_run_a_job_in_the_background.3F), there is no need for `;`.

```
{ echo "42" & sleep 3; }
```